# why is single dot slash needed at all to indicate current directory in php

Tags: php

I needed to do use "one dot before the slash" to make this PHP header redirect instruction work:

```
header("Location: ./retrieve.php?hash=$hash");
```

I understand that `./` means *current directory*.

So then why didn't plain `header("Location: retrieve.php?hash=$hash");`, without the "single dot slash," work?

Is it due to the query fragment `?hash=$hash` ?

---

Update: In a different project, I see that I did this: `header('Location:page2.html');` and it worked. Any thoughts on why I may not have had to precede with `./` there?

Comment: Because this is the convention. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location#Relative_URL_example / https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2

Comment: @Marged Thanks for the response. In a different project, I see that I did this: `header('Location:page2.html');` and it worked. Any thoughts on why I may not have had to precede with `./` there?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the initial relative path segment? What HTTP header debugging steps did you attempt so far? Any thoughts on reading [RFC7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) et al?

Comment: @mario Another way to think about my question is: why is something available to indicate the current directory when it's always implied by default? Thank you for the link you gave. Reading between the lines it seems to indicate that when fragments are involved, relative referencing should not be assumed.